# Trying to configure m2eclipse behind proxy

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to run m2eclipse on a workstation behind a proxy. I have configured Eclipse and Meven's settings.xml to recognize the proxy.
Yet I still get the following message every time I try and update something:
    *Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2*

Comment: Can you post the section of your `settings.xml`? Does Maven work from the command line?

Comment: Works fine from command line. Apparently, this is a known m2eclipse issue. what I do now, is build via command line and use mvn eclipse:eclipse. This refreshes the referenced libraries in eclipse, and allows to continue devlopment

Comment: please check this [reply][1].
Though if there is problem get back to me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540105/1802348

Answer (score 0):

Configure your eclipse network settings to support the proxy and try.